# SQL not exist issue

Tags: sql, exists

Having a bit of trouble dealing with not exist clause in a query.

I have three tables:

**Meal**

```
no_meal integer
type_meal varchar(255)
```

**Consumed**

```
no_meal integer
designation varchar(255)
quantity integer
```

**Food**

```
designation varchar(255)
quantity integer
type varchar(255)
```

Quantity in food is quantity stored and quantity in consumed is consumed quantity so, they will differ and thus natural inner join won't cut it.

- Type of food can be 'drink' 'meat' 'fish' and so on.
- Type of meal can be 'Breakfast' 'Lunch' 'Dinner'

I want a query that will tell me the drinks that have been consumed in all types of meals.

I've been toggling and testing code but can't get it right. At the moment I'm trying this:

```
SELECT Consumed.designation
FROM Consumed
WHERE NOT EXISTS

(SELECT type_meal
 FROM Consumed, Food, Meal
 WHERE Consumed.designation = Food.designation
 AND Consumed.no_meal = Meal.no_meal
 AND type = 'Drink'
 ORDER BY Food.designation)

EXCEPT

(SELECT type_meal
 FROM Meal);
```

How the hell do I get it right?

Thanks for input.

**EDIT**:

I'll add some data in order to make it clearer.

**Food**

```
Steak   100    Meat
Water   200    Drink
Coca cola    300   Drink
```

**Meal**

```
0001     Breakfast
0002     Lunch
0003     Dinner
```

**Consumed**

```
0001     Water       50
0002     Steak       20
0001     Coca cola   20
0003     Water        5
0002     Water       15
```

Now, I want to know which drink has been consumed in every meal, which will only give water.

Hope I cleared some minds about the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twist your mind a little bit, and think with double negatives ....

> I want [...] the drinks that have been consumed in all types of meals.

You want all drinks for which there are NO meal types for which that drink is NOT part of the meal type:

```
select distinct f.designation 
from food f 
where 
  type = 'Drink' and 
  not exists (
    select * 
    from meal m1
    where not exists (
      select *  
      from meal m2
      join consumed c on c.no_meal = m2.no_meal
      where 
        m1.no_meal = m2.no_meal and
        c.designation = f.designation
    )
  )
```

This is called [relational division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/).

Comment: Right on!!!! That's what I wanted :) but the nested not exists confused me alot :/ Thanks for input

Answer (score 1):

Now I understand what you want...

```
SELECT designation
FROM Food
WHERE designation IN (
    SELECT designation 
    FROM Consumed
    GROUP BY designation
    HAVING Count(DISTINCT no_meal) = (
        SELECT Count(*) FROM Meal
    )
)
WHERE type = 'Drink'
```

Comment: quantity isn't needed for this querie. I just put it there because it differs and natural inner join can't be used.

Comment: What I need is the food designation of type 'Drink' that was consumed in every type of meal. If you don't use Food, how can you distinguish Meat and Fish from Drink?

Answer (score 1):

> I want a query that will tell me the drinks that have been consumed in all types of meals.

Your edit did clear things up. Note that following query will not work if the combination `Designation, Type`in `Consumed`is not unique but I'm guessing it will be.

```
SELECT  
    c.Designation
FROM
    (SELECT  
         c.Designation
     FROM    
         Consumed c
     INNER JOIN 
         Meal m ON m.no_meal = c.no_meal
     GROUP BY
         c.Designation
     HAVING  
         COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Meal)) c
INNER JOIN 
    Food f ON f.Designation = c.Designation
WHERE
    f.Type = 'Drink'
```

Comment: Guess I didnt explain myself well enough. what I want is not the quantity consumed of a drink in every meal by type

I want to know if there was any drink that was consumed in all types of meal.

I'll add some example data to the main page in order to explain better

Comment: After your edit, your original explanation actually makes sense <g>. I have altered the statement. Could you verify the results?

Comment: I've verified and it gave an empty table :/ I think it has to be done with not exist clause as given by Roopesh Shenoy

Comment: @Martin, I'm testing your patience here but I have (yet again) altered the query. The join with food should be placed outside the group by statement.

Comment: Don't worry about it. It's still an empty table however

Comment: <sigh> that's what you get for not having an SQL Server running to test one's queries </sigh>

Comment: @Martin, I've inserted the data in a MySQL database. The result is Water. Are you sure you've tried the latest edit? Are you sure you are working with the data you've given in your question?

Comment: I'm using a larger database than that, that was a short example. I've tested again and it still gives a blank database as opposed to the answer given by Lucero where I changed data and it responded as supposed.  Thanks alot for input and the time wasted.

Comment: lol, no problem. I have wasted your time to. Let's call it even ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from food f inner join
     consumed c_1 on c_1.designation = f.designation
where type='Drink' and
not exists -- to filter out drinks that are not a part of all the meals
(select 1 
from consumed c_2 inner join
     meal m_1 on m_1.no_meal = c_2.no_meal
where c_1.no_meal = c2.no_meal and
      c_1.designation = c2.designation and
 not exists (select 1 
               from meal m_2
              where m_1.no_meal = m_2.no_meal))
```

Comment: I ran it and added an 'and' before not exists and the result given was just the same as select*from food where type='Drink'

It seems the filter doesn't work

Comment: I think it's something like this too with not exists but I cant seem to get it right. the filter ain't working properly

Comment: Edit - added the and. Let me check the rest of the query once.

Comment: unfortunately it still gave the same thing. I was curious how to make it work with not exists because Lucero answer is a bit of a cheat and applies to this problem only where not exist would be more general way of resolving it

Comment: il give it another shot tomorrow.. :) too tired to think right now.. I am sure there is a way im just getting confused with the nested not exists..

Comment: Aww.. Jordao got there first.. kudos!

Answer (score 0):

I want a query that will tell me the drinks that have been consumed in all types of meals.

Here is the model structure and insertions you suggested:

```
USE SqlTests
GO

CREATE TABLE Meal (
    no_meal int
    , type_meal nvarchar(255)
)
GO

insert into Meal (no_meal, type_meal)
    values (1, N'Breakfast')
GO
insert into Meal (no_meal, type_meal)
    values(2, N'Lunch')
GO
insert into Meal (no_meal, type_meal)
    values(3, N'Dinner')
GO

CREATE TABLE Consumed (
    no_meal int
    , designation nvarchar(255)
    , quantity int
)
GO

insert into Consumed (no_meal, designation, quantity)
    values (1, N'Water', 50)
GO
insert into Consumed (no_meal, designation, quantity)
    values (2, N'Steak', 20)
GO
insert into Consumed (no_meal, designation, quantity)
    values (1, N'Coca cola', 20)
GO
insert into Consumed (no_meal, designation, quantity)
    values(3, N'Water', 5)
GO
insert into Consumed (no_meal, designation, quantity)
    values(2, N'Water', 15)
GO

CREATE TABLE Food (
    designation nvarchar(255)
    , quantity int
    , [type] nvarchar(255)
)
GO

insert into Food (designation, quantity, [type])
    values (N'Water', 200, N'Drink')
GO
insert into Food (designation, quantity, [type])
    values (N'Steak', 100, N'Meat')
GO
insert into Food (designation, quantity, [type])
    values (N'Coca cola', 200, N'Drink')
GO
```

Then, selecting with the proposed `SELECT`:

```
select c.designation
    from Consumed c
        inner join Meal m on m.no_meal = c.no_meal
        inner join Food f on f.designation = c.designation and f.[type] LIKE N'Drink'
    group by c.designation 
        having COUNT(c.designation) = (select COUNT(type_meal) from Meal)
```

Returns (at least on my database engine (SQL Server Express 2005)

`Water`

Is my information data correct?

Comment: That will give me every drink that was consumed ordered by type of meal, not every drink that was consumed in ALL types of meal

it would return:
breakfast   water
breafkast   cola
lunch       water
dinner      water

From here, I want it to give me only the drinks that appear in every meal type. In this example, water.

Was that clear enough? Don't know how much better can I explain it :S

Comment: Man this answer editor is just too bad :S I wrote it with paragraphs but they cut them down :/

Comment: @Martin: Thanks for your explanation. That is clear now. You got to take into account that many SO users are not native English speakers, so certain subtleties may be obvious for anglophones, but not for non English speakers, although one may speak and understand Ensligh well. Thanks for your understanding. I'll take your data sample and try it on my test database. =)

Comment: No problem Will, I'm not native english speaker either :)         Anyways, you can take the data I gave on front page and go from there, the goal is to have it deliver water.

Comment: @Martin: Edited my answer after having tested it. I was not far away from the solution. Please see the code sample provided.

Comment: Done and gives a blank table aswell. Thanks for your time and effort though, Lucero answer works using IN clause.

Comment: I don't get it, it works fine against the database I tested it. I'll include the table structure and the data inserted so that you may see.

Comment: It might be the given database in exmple that works with your test but it misses in the big one I'm testing it in. Also it goes with counting which isn't the most correct approach to this problem but I'll take it since it works and I'm sick of trying with not exist.
 I still have one more querie that I've been wasting alot of time with, I'll probably have to ask for help here soon :P

Comment: Can't really tell mate, I don't use the N'String' and I'm not familiar with them nor the [type]. From what I read it seems it works cause its pretty similar to Lucero answer